# What is a good electronics kit for the everyday inventor

Tags: capacitor, sensor, resistors

I am looking for a good electronics kit with lots of capacitors, trimmers, resistors, pots, diodes, transisters, leds and laser diodes, timers(like the 555), inductors ICs and common microchips, LOTS of sensors(temperature, gasses, radiation, light, sound, motion, etc etc etc) and sensor like pieces (like selenium chips), and a bunch of other things, a really good kit for all around for the chaotic inventor in me, What would you recommend? The more complete the kit, the better

Thank you for your time

PS it has been such a long time since ive used the names of these so if I have mixed some up or using the wrong name, please understand I am looking for everythign to make devices from smoke detectors, in communication devices over laser, wireless and such.

Thank you all again for your patience and taking the time to help, I understand how time consuming some of these posts can be and I hope I am not causing too much trouble